# Prove that is divisible by 7 (condition)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, number-systems

Determine the digit $ m $ tal, $ 888 ... 8m9 ... 999 $ (a number of times $8$ and $9$ repeat $50$ times) is divisible by $ 7 $

We have given a $101$-digit natural number divisible by $7$ defined as

$(1) \;\; N_m = \underbrace{888 \ldots 88}_{50} m \underbrace{999 \ldots 99}_{50}$.

Assume $m \neq 9$. Then by $(1)$

$(2) \;\; N_m + 1 $ We have given a 101-digit natural number divisible by $7$ defined as

$(1) \;\; N_m = \underbrace{888 \ldots 88}_{50} m \underbrace{999 \ldots 99}_{50}$.

Assume $m \neq 9$. Then by (1)

$(2) \;\; N_m + 1 = \underbrace{888 \ldots 88}_{50} (m+1) \underbrace{000 \ldots 00}_{50} $

I think this way is very technical, I don't know exactly ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $111\,111=7\times15\,873$. So, since $6\mid48$, the numbers$$\overbrace{88\ldots88}^{48\text{ times}}\ \text{ and }\ \overbrace{99\ldots88}^{48\text{ times}}$$are multiples of $7$. And your number is the sum of three numbers:

- $\displaystyle\overbrace{88\ldots88}^{48\text{ times}}\times10^{53}$;
- $\displaystyle88m99\times10^{48}$;
- $\displaystyle\overbrace{99\ldots99}^{48\text{ times}}$.

The first and the third of these numbers are multiples of $7$. And, since $7$ and $10$ are coprime, $7\mid88m99\times10^{48}$ if and only if $7\mid88m99$. Besides, this assertion holds if and only if $7\mid11m22$. With a little effort, you can see that this happens if and only ff $m=5$.

Comment: Perhaps there is even lesser effort considering that $88m99\equiv 4m01\pmod 7$.

Comment: How interesting! How interesting! How to conclude that $ 7 | 6k $ (divides numbers with multiple digits of 6), with $ k $ being a positive integer

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi If you divide $1$ by $7$ you get a decimal periodic number and the period has $6$ digits. So $$\dfrac17=\dfrac{\text{some number}}{999\,999}$$ Then $999\,999$ is a multiple of $7$.

Comment: @ajotatxe Sure! That was nice (this concerns your first comment).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:

$111,\!111$ is a multiple of $7$. In fact, it is the least multiple of $7$ whose every digit is $1$.